# Adding Page Titles and Meta Info to Home Page and Non Channal Entry Pages

Tags: seo

What is the best way to add custom page titles and meta info to non entry pages like the home page or a landing page for a portfolio? I want to give users the ability to edit the page title and meta info on these types of pages via the CP. I set up embedded variables to do this for my entry pages which works great but need a solution for these no channel entry pages. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most popular ways is to use [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables). It's perfect for handling all the 'etc' information which doesn't fit into a channel but where the user needs to be able to edit it from the control panel. It's commercial but it has many uses and is a common install.

Answer (score 1):

Digital Surgeons recently released an add-on to address this specific situation. Here's a snippet from their overview text:

> But unlike other SEO add-ons, you can manage SEO meta data on pages
>   which are not entries.

I haven't used it myself, but it looks pretty nifty. Take a look: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/surgeeo

Comment: @Brett: yes, I looked at this module today and seems best suited for the purpose of question :) .

Comment: @Bhashkar Glad to hear it!

Comment: Thanks just taken a look... being that I am not a server side developer this looks the the best solution for my needs. Many thanks to all contributions I hope others find this of use.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the channel to manage the page title and meta info. This channel would contain the field for these. Also, you should have a field type "Template Select" http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/template-select within this channel. In this way, this channel would have following fields:

- Page Tile
- Description
- Keywords
- Select the template (Template Select) field type

You can have following code example within your non-entry template:

```
{if segment_1}
{exp:channel channel="page_seo" search:template="{segment_1}/{segment_2}"}
<title>{page_title}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{description}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{keywords}" />
{/exp:channel}
{if:else}
<!-- To manage Home Page -->
{exp:channel channel="page_seo" search:template="home/index"}
<title>{page_title}</title>
<meta name="description" content="{description}" />
<meta name="keywords" content="{keywords}" />
{/exp:channel}
{/if}
```